# How does one identify a seed's species & variety?

Tags: genetics, botany, dna, seeds

How does one identify a seed's species & variety, could it be done by some means of DNA or by use of a microscope? 
Say for example, I had a pumpkin seed, I knew that it was a "small sugar pumpkin" variety, but how would one scientifically identify it to know that it was infact a small sugar pumpkin as well as a pumpkin without going through the process of planting it. Is there some kind of indicator on a DNA level that shows "This is what I am?"

My knowledge regarding biology is extremely basic, but I am very interested in knowing the full process of how this would work.

Comment: You sure, could identify plants by genotyping them. For many species, you can probably identify morphologically. For example, I am sure you are able to tell sunflower seed apart from flax seeds. Now, it will depend a bit about how accurate you want the identification to be. Sequencing would ultimately be most accurate (and most expensive) method.

Comment: @Remi.b: I disagree.  The most accurate method would be to plant it and see what grows :-)  I'm not sure sequencing would be that accurate, unless you have a pre-existing reference sequence for comparison.  Even then, I doubt that all small sugar pumpkins are genetically identical.  Could the gene(s) that differentiate a small sugar pumpkin from say an ordinary Halloween jack-o'-lantern one be reliably distinguished?

Comment: @jamesqf Ha ha that's right. Of course you;re right, identifying by genotyping will depends upon reference sequences. It will for sure be helpful to grouping related individuals in one's sample though.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, their name are "molecular marker". Every gene carrying a phenotype, quantitative or qualitative, is identified as an allele of every gene encoding for proteins. 
In order to identify a phenotype using just infos gained from DNA, you'll need a previous library made by these gene regions, were every polymorphism between them is associated with a phenotype. For example, a kind of marker used for this kind of work is **SSR** , or "Simple sequence repeats" : it is made by a simple sequence of DNA interspaced between two other region. The number of repeats of the internal sequence could be associated with a phenotype.

So, by a simple PCR you could amplify this regions:

[image: SSR amplification protocol]

And by a electrophoresis you could see how much repetitions are in your band, using just the molecular weight.
[Here](http://www.koreascience.or.kr/article/ArticleFullRecord.jsp?cn=E1PPBG_2008_v24n4_447) is an example of SSR used for phenotype/genotype screening